# I want to access this value from fedex response

Tags: php, fedex

I want get the last event from fedex tracking from magento.
i have call api for tracking and get the below response. now i want to get only last event from this responses

[image]

currently i am using following code but its return the

> FATAL ERROR : getTrackings() is not a member function.

```
  public function getTrackingStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('udpo/po_grid_collection');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter( 'main_table.udropship_status', '3' );
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id');
        $collection->getSelect()->join( array('ship_item'=> sales_flat_shipment_grid), 'ship_item.udpo_id = main_table.entity_id', array('ship_item.entity_id'));
        $collection->getSelect()->join( array('track_item'=> sales_flat_shipment_track), 'track_item.parent_id = ship_item.entity_id', array('track_item.track_number','track_item.carrier_code'));
        $data = $collection->getData(); 
        $count = count($data);  
        if($count > 0){
            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                $response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking($data[$i]['track_number']);
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($response->getCollection()->getFirstItem()->getData());
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this `print_r($response->getCollection()->getFirstItem()->getProgressdetail()->getActivity());` Let me know

Comment: sorry dude not work.  Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result::getCollection()

Answer (score 2):

`$response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking(track_number);
$trackData = $response->getAllTrackings();
$progressData = $trackData[0]->getData('progressdetail');
$deliveredStatus = $progressData[0]['activity'];`

finally i got proper answer for this question.